# Merging two consecutive values

Tags: r

I have a vector of different values, and I would like to merge and add two values together if a 5 is followed by a 3.

Input:

```
vector <- c(1, 2, 7, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 9, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 3)
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 7 4 3 8 8 2 6 9 4 4 5 6 2 6 8
```

So as you can see, the two occurrences of a three following a 5 have been added together to show 8. I'm sure there is a simple function that will do this in a matter of seconds, I just wasn't able to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vector <- c(1, 2, 7, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 9, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 3)

# get indices where 5 followed by 3
fives <- head(vector, -1) == 5 & tail(vector, -1) == 3   

# add three to fives
vector[fives] <- vector[fives] + 3  

# remove threes
vector <- vector[c(TRUE, !fives)] 
vector
# [1] 1 2 7 4 3 8 8 2 6 9 4 4 5 6 2 6 8
```

Comment: Could this also be used for a dataframe? I have a data frame with 9 columns and about 10,000 rows, and I'd like to merge two rows together if a column contains a 5 followed by a 3

Comment: Do you want to apply this to every column separately or apply this to all columns based on one single column? Maybe you can give a more explicit example.

Comment: So the important columns are ID, Matchtime, Scoreevent and accumulatedscore. Scoreevent contains different numbers ranging from -9 to 9. The accumulated score accumulates the score untill the ID changes, then both Scoreevent and Accumulated score reset back to zero. What I would like to do is if a 5 is followed by a 2 in the column Scoreevent, it would merge the two respective rows. So say if the row with the 5 had 123 in ID, 2053 in Matchtime, 5 in Scoreevent and 17 in accumulatedscore, and the row with the 3 had  123 in ID, 2117 in Matchtime, 3 in Scoreevent and 20 in accumulatedscore.

Comment: The rows would merge together an the eventual row would have:
`ID` as `123`, `Matchtime` as `2117`, `Scoreevent` as `8`, and `accumulatedscore` as `20`. Let me know if you don't understand, I'll just write another question

Comment: So after the merge, ID would be 123, Scoreevent would be 8, accumulated score would be 20? how about Matchtime?

Comment: I'll just write another question. Thank you though!

Comment: Definitely, I think that would be a more efficient way to get help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possibility:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 7, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 9, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 3)

A <- rbind(x[-length(x)], x[-1])
id <- which( colSums( abs(A - c(5, 3)) ) == 0 )

x[rbind(id, id + 1L)] <- c(8, NA)
na.omit(x)
```

---

**This solution was proposed to make it easier to extend to general cases (It may not best meets OP's need, but I just did it as an exercise.)**

In general, if you want to match a chunk `xc` in a vector `x`, we can do:

```
A <- t(embed(x, length(xc)))
id <- which(colSums(abs(A - rev(xc))) == 0)
```

Now `id` gives you the starting index of the matching chunk in `x`.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector <- c(1, 2, 7, 4, 3, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 9, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 6, 5, 3)
temp = rev(which((vector == 5) & (vector[-1] == 3)))  # find indexes of 5s followed by 3s

for (t in temp){
  vector = vector[-(t+1)]   # remove threes
  vector[t] = 8             # replace fives with eights
}
vector
# [1] 1 2 7 4 3 8 8 2 6 9 4 4 5 6 2 6 8
```