# How to remove any co-occurrence of sub-list elements from vector (R)

Tags: r

I review the python question [How to remove every occurrence of sub-list from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518601/how-to-remove-every-occurrence-of-sub-list-from-list).
Now I want to know how many creative ways are there in R.
For example, removing any occurrences of `sub_list` from the `main_list`.

```
main_list = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2 ,1)
sub_list = c(1,2)
```

desired result:  `2 3 4 2 2 1`

My suggestions:

```
a<-c()
for(i in 1:(length(main_list)-1)){
if (all(main_list[c(i,i+1)]==sub_list))
{a<-c(a,c(i,i+1))}
}
main_list[-a]
[1] 2 3 4 2 2 1
```

2

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("(12)","",paste0(main_list,collapse = "")),split = "")))
```

Ohh it is really dangerous. Let's try:

```
main_list = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 12, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1)
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("(12)","",paste0(main_list,collapse = "")),split = "")))
[1] 2 3 4 2 2 1
####However 
a<-c()
for(i in 1:(length(main_list)-1)){
if (all(main_list[c(i,i+1)]==sub_list))
{a<-c(a,c(i,i+1))}
}
main_list[-a]
[1]  2  3 12  4  2  2  1
```

### Update Sat Sep 08  2018

#### Benchmarking Solutions:

I Benchmarked solutions base on the memory and time, each solution takes, with a big vector of numbers and used `profmem` and `microbenchmark` libraries.

```
set.seed(1587)
main_list<-sample(c(8:13,102:105),size = 10000000,replace = T)
main_list<-c(c(8,9,12,103),main_list,c(8,9,12,103))   
sub_list<-c(8,9,12,103)
```

`d.b`'s solution does not work for `main_list` so I modified it as follows:

```
ML = paste(main_list, collapse = ",")  # collapse should not be empty
SL = paste(sub_list, collapse = ",")
out<-gsub(SL, "", ML)
out<-gsub("^\\,","",out)
out<-gsub("\\,$","",out)
out<-gsub("\\,,","\\,",out)
out<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(out,split = ",")))
```

The result:

```
  solution       seconds memory_byte memory_base seconds_base
  <chr>            <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
1 d.b              26.0    399904560        1           16.8 
2 Grothendieck_2    1.55  1440070304        3.60         1   
3 Grothendieck_1  109.    4968036376       12.4         70.3 
4 李哲源            2.17  1400120824        3.50         1.40
```

Any comment about the benchmarking?

Comment: Does an open question improve creativity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions.  The first one is obviously simpler and would be used if you favour clarity and maintainability while the second one has no package dependencies and is faster.

**1) zoo** Use a moving window to compare each subsequence of c(`main_list, sub_list)` having the required length to the `sub_list`.  (We append `sub_list` to ensure that there is always something to remove.)  This statements returns TRUE or FALSE according to whether the current position is the end of a matching subsequence. Then compute the TRUE index numbers and from that the indices of all elements to be removed and remove them.

```
library(zoo)

w <- length(sub_list)
r <- rollapplyr(c(main_list, sub_list), w, identical, sub_list, fill = FALSE)
main_list[-c(outer(which(r), seq_len(w) - 1, "-"))]
## [1] 2 3 4 2 2 1
```

**2) Base R**.  The middle line setting `r` has the same purpose as the corresponding line in (1) and the last line is the same as the last line in (2) except we use `+` instead of `-` due to the fact that `embed` effectively uses left alignment.

```
w <- length(sub_list)
r <- colSums(t(embed(c(main_list, sub_list), w)) == rev(sub_list)) == w
main_list[-c(outer(which(r), seq_len(w) - 1, "+"))]
## [1] 2 3 4 2 2 1
```

Comment: Yes, `embed` is a good function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41839433/4891738, the only inconvenience is that we need a `rev`. Are you sure that you don't need to protect `x[-ind]` by testing that `length(ind) > 0L`?

Comment: As long as `sub_list` has strictly positive length the index length in the last line of either solution above is also strictkly positive so there is no need to test it.  One could test whether `sub_list` has zero length if one wanted to address that edge case.

Comment: Yes, when I added the second solution I modified the first to use the same trick.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that does this general thing.

- `xm` is a main list of integer / character / logical values;
- `xs` is a sub list of integer /character / logical values.

It is required that `length(xm) > length(xs)` but no such check is made right now.

---

```
foo <- function (xm, xs) {
  nm <- length(xm)
  ns <- length(xs)
  shift_ind <- outer(0:(ns - 1), 1:(nm - ns + 1), "+")
  d <- xm[shift_ind] == xs
  first_drop_ind <- which(.colSums(d, ns, length(d) / ns) == ns)
  if (length(first_drop_ind) > 0L) {
    drop_ind <- outer(0:(ns - 1), first_drop_ind, "+")
    return(xm[-drop_ind])
    } else {
    return(xm)
    }
  }

main_list = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2 ,1)
sub_list = c(1,2)
foo(main_list, sub_list)
#[1] 2 3 4 2 2 1
```

**Explanation**

```
xm <- main_list
xs <- sub_list

nm <- length(xm)
ns <- length(xs)
shift_ind <- outer(0:(ns - 1), 1:(nm - ns + 1), "+")
MAT <- matrix(xm[shift_ind], ns)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#[1,]    2    1    2    3    1    2    4    2    2
#[2,]    1    2    3    1    2    4    2    2    1
```

So the first step is a shifting and matrix representation, as above.

```
LOGIC <- MAT == xs
#      [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
#[1,] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

If a co-occurrence is found, a column should contain all `TRUE`, i.e., the `colSums` should be `ns`. In this way we can identify the location of the first value of the matching.

```
first_drop_ind <- which(colSums(LOGIC) == ns)
#[1] 2 5
```

Now we need to expand it to cover the subsequent values after those initial matches.

```
drop_ind <- outer(0:(ns - 1), first_drop_ind, "+")
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    5
#[2,]    3    6
```

Finally we remove values at those positions from `xm`:

```
xm[-drop_ind]
#[1] 2 3 4 2 2 1
```

Note that in the function, the matrix is not explicitly formed. `.colSums` is used instead of `colSums`.

---

*watch out for bug*

*The `if ... else ...` in the function is necessary. If no match is found then `drop_ind` would be `integer(0)`, and using `xm[-drop_ind]` gives `xm[integer(0)]` which is `integer(0)`.*

---

**comparison with `zoo::rollapplyr`**

```
## require package `zoo`
bar <- function (xm, xs) {
  w <- length(xs)
  r <- rollapplyr(xm, w, identical, xs, fill = FALSE)
  if (length(r) > 0L) {
    return(xm[-c(outer(which(r), seq_len(w) - 1, "-"))])
    } else {
    return(xm)
    }
  }

set.seed(0)
xm <- sample.int(10, 10000, TRUE)
xs <- 1:2

library(zoo)

system.time(a <- foo(xm, xs))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.004   0.000   0.001 

system.time(b <- bar(xm, xs))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.276   0.000   0.273 

all.equal(a, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

I guess that `rollapplyr` is slower is because

- it needs to first coerce `xm` to a "zoo" object;
- internally it uses `lapply` so that there is a frequent jump between R and C.

Comment: Personally speaking I prefer to a full Rcpp solution, but some efforts are needed to deal with different data types. As a C programmer I am not familiar with C++'s template approach so this is not straightforward to me. In C I could use macro to achieve the same effect. But anyway, I might revisit this case sometime in future.